# Need help in Circle Progress Ring

Tags: lightning, javascript, html, css3

Need to create a circle progress ring that increases everytime on my application, when an input field(answer) is filled for every question.

Answer (score 0):

In lightning component you can use [Progress Bar](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressBar/example) and use variant as 'circular'

Comment: Your suggestion looks valid, but when I added variant='circular', it did not change to circular. Can you give some sample code to me. Also where to add my field that it checks it is filled, If something like that is required. Thanks.